# Robotic legs technologies

Tags: legged

what robotic leg technologies are available.

i'm sorry if this is a basic question i am a software developer looking to get into the field of robotics. i am particularly interested in robotic legs that are similar to those used on Boston Dynamics ATLAS robot.

what is the mechanism required that allows it to move its joints so quickly. if you see any videos of many of Boston Dynamics robots they make an engine sound (presumably because it uses an engine), but i cant find any details in the configuration that is being used.

Comment: Welcome to *robotics* X0r0N, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Answer (score 1):

Their [page for the ATLAS robot](http://www.bostondynamics.com/robot_Atlas.html) states the joints are hydraulically activated.

A number of their other big robots also use hydraulics. For example [Big Dog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BigDog) uses a small motorbike/go-kart engine to run a hydraulic pump which drives cylinders.

(Very high budget stuff for an individual developer to get into, I suspect.)

Comment: thanks for that. i will have to find some other method for my robots movement.